# PHP Files downloading on page load rather than executing - NGINX

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, subdomain

I have set up a sub domain in root directory along with our actual domain. 
In the root directory the two folders are as follows:

domain.com 
sub.domain.com

When going to domain.com (which already existed) things work as expected.
When going to sub.domain.com (which is a wordpress installation) the `index.php` file just downloads and the page does not load or execute.

In my `etc/nginx/sites-available/sub.domain.com.conf` I have:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/sub.domain.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name sub.domain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

I have remembered to restart the nginx server, however, we do use php-fpm so I'm not sure if this could be related.

It must be related to PHP, because when replacing the wordpress installation for a basic index.html file, the page loads as expected. Does anyone know what might be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the following to my configuration:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```